# How can I replace string during Compilation

Tags: angular, firebase

I am getting exactly '\n' back and I want to replace it during compilation with the following code but, I am getting an error. How do I do this?

It's a full text object from firebase firestore. I have also tried to use `<pre>` and pre-wrap but nothing working.

> error is error TS2339: Property 'replacingOccurrences' does not exist on type 'Project'.

```
this.projectsserivice.getProjects()
    .subscribe(projects => {
      this.projects = projects;
     this.projects.forEach(element => {
       const newstr = element.replacingOccurrences('\n', '<br>');
       console.log(newstr);
     });
    }, errmess => this.ProerrMess = <any>errmess);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is javascript, there is no `replacingOccurrences` in any standard Prototype.

I see that `element` is a `Project`, that I imagine is a class of yours. Are you sure that you defined a method called `replacingOccurrences`?

If you want to replace all text occurrences in a string, then you might need to use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

If Project is an object containing some strings and you want to do the replace an each string contained, you can do something like this:

```
Object.keys(element)
    .filter(item => typeof(item) == 'string') //only using replace on strings
    .forEach(item => element.item = element.item.replace("\n", "<br/>"));
```

This piece of code only alters first level children.

So if your Project only contains, as you said in the comments, 3 strings and no inner Object, your code should work like this:

```
this.projectsserivice.getProjects()
    .subscribe(projects => {
        this.projects = projects;
        this.projects.forEach(element => {
            Object.keys(element)
                .filter(item => typeof(item) == 'string' && element.item) //only using replace on strings
                .forEach(item => element.item = element.item.replace("\n", "<br/>"));
        });
    }, errmess => this.ProerrMess = <any>errmess);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! i tried replace same error! element is a actually a project and i am getting that from firestore. What i want to do is replace all the new line string that is rendering from fire store exactly how it's stored.

Comment: then you should call replace on each string object contained in your Project object

Comment: my object from firestore is
"title": " ", 
"description": "\n",
url
And i have the \n inside the text in description

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, i am still getting the \n back exactly and getting "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Comment: try adding `&& element.item` in the filter, like I wrote in the edit

Comment: @R.Ovis Glad I helped :) consider accepting my answer